# jquery each prevent alert from looping

Tags: jquery

Take a look on this code first. Example I have 5 input fields that has required class.

```
var errMsg = "This is required!"

$(function() {
   $(".required").each(function() {
      if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val == errMsg) {
         $(this).val(errMsg);
      }
      else {
         alert("This should alert once");
      }
   });
}
```

I know that if the field has value, it will alert 5 times. How can I prevent it? How can I alert it once? I already use

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation
event.preventDefault
```

Comment: You might want to `$.trim` the value before comparing to the empty string: `$.trim($(this).val());`.

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Two options:

1. Stop the `each` loop:

   You can stop the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop by returning `false`:

   ```
   var errMsg = "This is required!"

   $(function() {
      $(".required").each(function() {
         if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val == errMsg) {
            $(this).val(errMsg);
         }
         else {
            alert("This should alert once");
            return false; // <=== Stop `each`
         }
      });
   }
   ```

   See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for details.
2. Set a flag:

   If you want the loop to continue but for the `alert` to only happen once, use a flag:

   ```
   var errMsg = "This is required!"

   $(function() {
      var alerted = false;
      $(".required").each(function() {
         if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val == errMsg) {
            $(this).val(errMsg);
         }
         else {
            if (!alerted) {
                alerted = true;
                alert("This should alert once");
            }
         }
      });
   }
   ```

   If doing this (letting the loop continue), see [Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610469/jquery-each-prevent-alert-from-looping/5610503#5610503). He moved the alert outside the `each`, which offers you more flexibility in how you present the message, and is just cleaner.

---

**Off-topic**: *Every time* you call `$()`, it makes 3-4 function calls and allocates memory. If you find yourself repeating the same `$()` in a function, consider doing it *once* and reusing it. So instead of:

```
if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val == errMsg) {
    $(this).val(errMsg);
}
```

do this

```
var $this = $(this);
if($this.val() == "" || $this.val == errMsg) {
    $this.val(errMsg);
}
```

Most of the time it won't matter much as you won't be doing things thousands of times over, but it's a good habit to get into. Obviously, *don't* cache the result if you're doing a DOM query and the DOM may have changed between one call and the next...

Comment: Then it will only put the message in the first empty field.

Comment: @Guffa: Yeah, you commented as I realized he may want the loop to continue and added the second option.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the alert outside the loop, and then you need a varaible to keep track of whether there was any empty fields:

```
var errMsg = "This is required!"

$(function() {
   var showMsg = false;
   $(".required").each(function() {
      if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val == errMsg) {
         $(this).val(errMsg);
      } else {
         showMsg = true;
      }
   });
   if (showMsg) alert("This should alert once");
}
```

Comment: If anybody understands how this is working, this is the right solution. the others are missing the fact that the alert needs to be outside of the $.each loop

Comment: @Bobby: I agree that Guffa's solution is good (and have upvoted it), but there's nothing in the OP's question that *requires* that the alert be outside the loop. (This could be because the question isn't all that clear.) Still, this is the right approach. The OP might even consider counting the invalid fields and showing a count. (And not using `alert`, but that's a whole different thing.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
   $(".required").each(function() {
      if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val == errMsg) {
         $(this).val(errMsg);
      }
      else {
         alert("This should alert once");
         return false;  // break the loop;
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Then it will only put the message in the first empty field.

Answer (score 1):

use a flag.
This way, you wont break the loop  after alerting the message, but alert it only once:

```
var errMsg = "This is required!"

$(function() {
    var ok = true;   
    $(".required").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val == errMsg) {
            $(this).val(errMsg);
        }
        else {
           if(ok){
               alert("This should alert once");
               ok = false;
           }
       }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
    $(function() {
    var errMsg = "This is required!";
    $alert_once = 0;
   $(".required").each(function() {
      if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == errMsg) {
         $(this).val(errMsg);
         $alert_once = 1;
      }
      else {
         alert("This should alert once");
      }
   });
   if ($alert_once == 0) {
        alert('Alert Once');
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.